# How yo fix port issue in ruby on rails. Port is not working on 3000 and im unable to select different port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[This is the output im getting whenever im trying to fix port or run the server or trying to run some command. Its not working on any port.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpW9x.png)

Comment: What command are you using to run your server?

Comment: You are not in correct folder. Goto root folder of your application and then run the rails/rake command

Comment: Please don't post picture of console output. Simply paste the text directly into your question. Pictures can be difficult to view on some devices and they make it impossible to copy and paste text into answers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Your question doesn't meet the guidelines for an acceptable question. We need more information, most likely some code and the problem description, all in your question, not linked to an image. Links to off-site resources age, rot, then break, resulting in a question that'll make no sense.

Answer (score -2):

goto config/puma.rb  in you application, here you will find the port to change.

```
 port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
```